# how to set zoom only for the x-axis?

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I use:

```
ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, dataset, mRenderer,"yy-MMM");
```

Generate the graph works :)

I would like to set the zoom only for the x-axis

I found a method `mRenderer.setZoomInLimitY(parameter);` but I do not know what is the parameter.

how to do it?

Comment: Here parameter is float u can put any float lik 5, 10 ,15 etc. But I want to know what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I want disable zoom for y-axies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
   mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false); 
   mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, false);
```